# Browserify get external JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, browserify

I am seeking advice on the best way to get external JSON data.

I am using browserify and included JSON data, looks like `const data = require('mydata.json')`.

However, I don't want to compile browserify JavaScript file whenever JSON data gets an update. I am thinking if browserify is able to call JSON which is located externally, thus, I can just update JSON file.

Another options for me is to use `getJSON()` to call externally JSON file, which I think this method is not an efficient way to do.

If someone has a better option? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to use Browserify to build two separate bundles: one for the JSON data; and another for the app. The app can then `require` the data from the other bundle.

As an example, create the following files.

A **`data.json`** for the data:

```json
{ "name": "alice" }
```

An **`index.js`** for the application:

```js
var data = require("data.json");
console.log(data);
```

And an **`index.html`** to load the example bundles:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>so-41762055</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./bundle-data.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use the following commands to build the data and app bundles:

```
browserify --require ./data.json:data.json > bundle-data.js
browserify --exclude data.json index.js > bundle-app.js
```

Once you have two bundles, you can rebuild the data bundle and leave the application bundle untouched.

Comment: The answer is very clear and easy to understand.  Many thanks!